# OverlayFS hangs when an underlying CIFS lowerdir has network issues

Tags: linux, mount, samba, overlay, autofs

I have an example setup:

```
overlay /data/all overlay noauto,x-systemd.automount,lowerdir=/data/local:/data/remote 0 0
//myhomeserver/data /data/remote cifs iocharset=utf8,ro,credentials=/data/remote.credentials 0 0
```

Now, problems arise when **myhomeserver** can't be reached. Most cases, connection drops, comes back online, but `/data/all` no longer works (hangs), `df` hangs a bit and in the end it outputs a classic CIFS-related *myhomeserver: Host is down* message.

How to handle this in the most graceful way possible with current tech? I'm on latest stable Debian for both servers. Data is always accessed through overlayfs `/data/all`. I would require something like:

- `/data/all` overlayfs should never hang or at least do it minimally and recover
- `/data/all` should expose available data from `/data/local` no matter the state of `/data/remove`
- `/data/remote` should be available best-effort, that is, recover automatically after a downtime, and upon recovery, `/data/all` should again expose its contents

I think that **systemd** could somewhat help but don't know how I would use it properly in such a setup, can't find any examples. Maybe **autofs** could also help? Never used that though..